# How to document .c and .h files with Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I am attempting my first documentation using Doxygen. My firmware is written in c. I have documented the main file and I want to document a library. The library has a .c and .h file.

How could I document the library?
Should I define two independed groups using the @defgroup?

For example for the .c file:

```
** @defgroup ble_raw_data.c
 *  @{
 */
```

and for the .h file:

```
** @defgroup ble_raw_data.h
 *  @{
 */
```

Is this correct? Or is there any more elegant approach?

Thanks in advance
Nick

Comment: For this you don't need groups. Just document the the function (in .c or .h file, better not in both!) and let doxygen process both the .c and .h files and see the results, after this you can do the fine tuning (when required).

Comment: Thanks it works great!! But what are the purpose of the modules and groups? Could you give a practical example?